# How to run load app configuration data asynchronously on application startup

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a .Net Core 3.1 application and at startup I need to read some secrets from KV. Since this operation is async this is the approach I have used.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        services.AddApplicationSettings(Configuration);
        ...
    }
    
    public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationSettings(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var applicationSettings = new ApplicationSettings(configuration);
        applicationSettings.ReadApplicationSettingsAsync().Wait();

        services.AddSingleton<IApplicationSettings>(applicationSettings);
        return services;
    }
```

Is there an option to obtain in an async way so I will not need to call .Wait();

Comment: What is KV? Are you using a specific product or something you created yourself? If it's an existing product are you sure there isn't a configuration provider available already? If you check the docs you'll see there are a *lot* of config providers that load from remote services. I suspect all of them call `.Wait()` or `.Result` in the end. The config provider base classes have no async overloads

Comment: KV - key vault
I was looking for something like the code proposed here:
https://andrewlock.net/running-async-tasks-on-app-startup-in-asp-net-core-3/

Comment: A *lot* of products are key/value stores. Redis can be used as a KV store, so can Couchbase.  What do you refer to? The article you linked to has nothing to do with configuration. This code runs *after* the entire host is configured and built. Before that step there's no application pipeline and only a single thread so async operations offer no benefit